# Apache Wicket: Disabling validators on onCancel within a Wizard

Tags: java, validation, web, wicket

I have a wizard, in which many of the panels provide forms, with their respective validtors. If I click on the cancel button within the wizard, I am unable to run the onCancel logic without the forms being validated. [The only job that the cancel button will be doing is redirection] Is there a way to disable the validation just for that situation?

I am using Apache Wicket 6.10, and the Wizard control is coming from Wicket-Extensions 6.10.

Answer (score 3):

You should set Button.setDefaultFormProcessing(false) to skip validation.

Also take a look at this link for an example: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Multiple+submit+buttons

Comment: This does not appear to work: https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/browse/~br=sandbox%402fcomponent-queueing/wicket-git/wicket-extensions/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/extensions/wizard/CancelButton.java?r=d2be7fd368cdca02dd7481490de587bcc1a6e4cd

I'm still getting a validation issue.